# Installing python

Tags: python, path, command, installation

I have tried to install Python 3.4 on Windows 7 using the following guide 
I have added the following to my Path in system environmental variables

```
C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts;
```

When I open up the Python command line and type the following (as instructed in the tutorial) I receive an error message printed below

Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:15:05) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

**python --version** <- what i type

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'python' is not defined

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You have to write `python --version` in the systems command line, not in the interactive Python interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to type python --version from the command line. Not when you are already running python.

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Chris>cd ..

C:\Users>cd ..

C:\>python
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:15:05) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> python --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'python' is not defined
>>>

Comment: I am having the same error with the CMD as shown above

Comment: C:\Users\Chris>python --version

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, you need to run your command from the command prompt:

```
python --version
```

However, if you are in the python interpreter, you can find the current version with this code:

```
import sys
print (sys.version)
```

Comment: I am having the same trouble in cmd...Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Chris>cd ..

C:\Users>cd ..

C:\>python
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:15:05) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> python --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'python' is not defined
>>>